# tap not list: "ERROR: each layout item may only occur once"

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

It's a coredata+cloudkit based App. Crash happened only when the icloud user **firstly** using the app. the user create a book, a BookView and only one BookView shows up in LazyVGrid, everything is OK. Then when I tap the book view, crash as "ERROR: each layout item may only occur once".

I search the internet, everyone says this error occurs only when repeated identifiers in Grid. Book.id is unique and I add .id(book.id) for the BookView.

Crash will occur when grid shows up if repeated identifiers, why my code will crash when tap the BookView in grid?

After this, restart the app, tap the BookView, it's ok. remove the book, clear the grid, create a new book, tap it, everything is fine. It happens only when the icloud user **firstly** using the app. I have already use up my appids.

Confused, any suggestion？

Some codes here:

```
public class Book: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var author: String?
    @NSManaged public var cover: Data?
    @NSManaged public var createAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var creatorName: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var chapters: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var subscribes: NSSet?
}

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Subscribe.lastAccessAt, ascending: false)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@ AND isSubscribed = YES AND isHidden = NO", Manager.shared.myId ?? ""), animation: .default) private var subscribes: FetchedResults<Subscribe>
    var books: [Book] { subscribes.compactMap { $0.book }.filter { $0.isDeleted == false } }

    var booksView: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 4) {
            ForEach(books, id: \.id) { book in
                BookView(book: book, extViewTypes: [.progress, .moreInfo], onMoreInfo: onMoreInfo)
                    .id(book.id)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        onBookTapped(book: book)
                    }
            }
        }.padding(4)
    }

    func onBookTapped(book: Book) {
        Manager.shared.play(book: book)
    }

    func play() {
            ....
            context.perform {
                subscribe.lastAccessChapter = chapter
                ckdbManager.save()
            }
            ....
    }
```

Comment: To my mind `id(book.id)` is not needed here (or even harmful) - try to remove it.

Comment: @Asperi I think so.

Comment: @Asperi I think subscribe update in play() effect Grid, but why?

Comment: I print books, found that two books with the same data appeared in my circumstance, why? I can add removingDuplicates() to fix this. but why??